# javascript, bind `this` dont work

Tags: javascript

i have `map` object and in property `markersLocation` i bind `this` so i can use it inside function but insted `this` is something else

```
(function(){
  var map = {

    ...
    init: function(options){

        ...
      this.markersLocation();
        ...
    },

    // markers
    placeMarker: function(distrybutors, instalators){
      for (var i = 0; i < distrybutors.length; i++) {
        var LatLng = this.getGeoAddress(distrybutors[i].address);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.mapObj,
        position: LatLng
      });

      }
    }.bind(this),

    markersLocation: function() {

      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
          var jsonData = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
          if (jsonData.status) {
            console.log(this);
            this.placeMarker(jsonData.distrybutors, jsonData.instalators);
          } else {
            console.log('error');
          }
          console.log(jsonData.instalators);
        }
      }.bind(this)
      xmlHttp.open("GET", document.querySelector('#urlAdress').value, true); // true for asynchronous
      xmlHttp.send();
    }.bind(this),
  }

  map.init({
    location: "50.1943227,17.8434933"

  });
})();
```

and i get this `TypeError: this.placeMarker is not a function` 
i wanted to use `this` as `map` object, what i need to correct to make it work that way.

Comment: You're not calling the bind from inside the object, your'e calling it from inside an anonymous function. Since the anonymous function is not part of any object therefore the `this` inside the function where bind was called is the global object (or undefined if in strict mode). Therefore the `this` you're binding to points to the global object (in browsers this would be `window`)

Comment: Because when the code executes, *this* has not been set so it either defaults to the global object or is *undefined* in strict mode.

Comment: i just removed `bind(this)` and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding a value for `this` at the time the `map` object is declared.

As far as the runtime is concerned, until it finishes evaluating the object literal, there is no `map` object. So `this` will refer to `window`.

If you remove the `.bind(this)` calls on the top level methods it should work.

```
placeMarker: function(distrybutors, instalators){
  for (var i = 0; i < distrybutors.length; i++) {
    var LatLng = this.getGeoAddress(distrybutors[i].address);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.mapObj,
      position: LatLng
    });

  }
}.bind(this),  // `this` is not what you think it is
```

Seeing as you're already evaluating this in an IIFE, you might want to go the whole way and rewrite it as a class.

```
function Map() {
  this.init = function() { };

  this.placeMarker = function() {

  }.bind(this);

  // ...
}
```

This way (so long as you use `new Map()` or `Map.call({})` there'll be no ambiguity about the value of this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be there when it's called:

```
placeMarker.bind(this)
markersLocation.bind(this)
```

You can follow more from there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind